# Is there a way to give an Android in-app subscription to someone for free?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I've seen similar posts from a while back that say that the only way to do this is to have the person actually purchase the subscription, and then I can process a refund. Is there any update on this, or is that still the only way to give a specific person a free subscription?

A friend of mine has a solution with an iPhone app... The person that requests the app for free gives my friend their UDID, and my friend puts it into a database. The app checks the database for the specific UDID each time it is run, and if it is there, the subscription content is provided. Otherwise, it must be purchased.

But this doesn't seem feasible for Android, because Android devices [don't really have unique IDs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html); and I don't know how a user can find this device ID on an Android, anyway.

Comment: @KevinDTimm If so, that might be a partial solution, but `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` doesn't return a value for tablets or music devices. Where can one find their IMEI on the device?

Comment: And you can also generate a new ID if you install another ROM or use TitaniumBackup etc.

Comment: @AndroidPenguin - that should be such a small percentage for the OP as to be irrelevant

Comment: You could do a callback to server to register the software and assign some sort of userID, then use that userID for the freebie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a subscription to the best of my knowledge, unless you set them up with a test account. For refunds for in app managed items, you can control what a refund does however and hence it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the user up with a test account. The test accounts work based off of email address. If you provide their Google email address, it should allow you to do anything, including giving them a free subscription.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of test accounts that Google will allow?

Comment: If there is, it is reasonably large. I haven't personally seen such a limitation.

Comment: It gives access for approximate 5 minutes then it renews and send mail with information. This not the solution. Check this link, https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions